# How can I format/indent my cone in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, indentation, shortcut

I use a MSI pc with windows 11 O/S I tried copying a code from a documentation and pasted it in vs code. I need to format that to a readable format but I tried the given default shortcuts as well but nothing is happening.

I need to format my codes into a more readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can download VSCode extensions from the [VSCode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) or in VSCode itself with the extensions side panel. Search for the name of the programming language you are using, then run the formatter by selecting it from the right click menu.